# Comparing estimators for stochastic approximation

Tags: gradient-descent, estimators, stochastic-approximation

Given a stochastic approximation setting

$f(\theta^*) = \max\limits_\theta\mathbb{E}[F(\theta,X)]$

where our goal is to maximize $f(\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ using a series of samples of the estimator which depends on the random variable $X$: $F(\cdot, X_1), F(\cdot, X_2), \ldots$

How can you prove that $F$ is better or worse than some other estimator $G$ (using e.g. stochastic gradient descent)?

Consider the case where $G(\theta, X, Y) =Y \cdot F(\theta, X)$ with $Y$ sampled (independently of $X$ and $\theta$) from the normal distribution, $Y \sim \eta(1,1)$. In this case, $Y$ is just noise irrelevant to $f(\theta)$ and won't help us maximize it --- surely, if we had a choice we would choose $F$ over $G$.

Since $\mathbb{E}[Y]=1$ then $G$ is unbiased (or at least no more biased than $F$): $\mathbb{E}[F]=\mathbb{E}[G]$. As far as I understand, variance or variance-to-mean-ratio are not useful metrics for comparing $F$ to $G$ in regards to their usefulness as an estimator for maximizing $f(\theta)$.

Comment: Stochastic gradient descent is one of many algorithms for finding the max / min of a function; the function shouldn't depend on the optimization algorithm, but on the problem you are facing.   Given that, I'm not sure what you mean by "... $F$ is better or worse than some other estimator $G$ for stochastic gradient descent?"   It would be more typical to say "... stochastic gradient descent is better for finding the optimum of $F$ than <<insert optimization algorithm here>>?"

Comment: @jbowman I don't know if the choice of optimization alg. is relevant to the question, which is why I specified it.